# How to fill blank array with in loop using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I want have two tables in mysql "taxiInfo" and "booking",Now i just want to show/fetch status of every taxi
(whether every taxi is "booked" or "aviliable" ),

Here is my table "taxiInfo"

```
id          userId          TotalTaxi           
1           2               3   
2           4               2
```

Here is my table "booking"

```
id      userId          taxiId          serviceDate
1       2               1               2019-10-30
```

Now first of all i fetch "TotalTaxi" from mysql and check whether taxi is booked or not using loop,Here is my code

```
$this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('taxiInfo');
        $this->db->where('userId', $_POST['userId']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
            {
                $rows = $query->row_array();
                 $totaltaxi=$rows['TotalTaxi'];
                $team=array();
                for($i=1;$i<=$totaltaxi;$i++)
                {
                    $date = date('Y-m-d');
                    $this->db->select('b.*');
                    $this->db->from('booking b');
                    $this->db->where('userId', $_POST['userId']);
                    $this->db->where('taxiId', $i);
                    $this->db->where('serviceDate', $date);
                    $querys = $this->db->get();
                    $res = $querys->result_array();
                    echo "<pre>";print_R($res);
                }
```

Now i am getting following result , now if taxi is "aviliable" then i am getting blank array, i want to get result for both condition (whether taxi is booked not aviliable)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [userId] => 2
            [taxiId] => 1
        )
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
```

Right now i have four values in array (1 taxi booked and 3 are aviliable)
But how can i merge all values in single array ? I want output like following array/format

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [userId] => 2
            [taxinumber] => 1
            [status] => booked
        )
)
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [userId] => 2
            [taxinumber] => 2
            [status] => aviliable
        )
)
...
```

Comment: What about if there is 2 records for `user_id` 2 in `taxiInfo`? Your code should not working.

Comment: @nmfzone: No there will be always 1 record for every single user

Comment: @nmfzone: My problem is " i want to show status of every taxi (whether exist in "booking" table or not ") in other words i want to fill blank array ( if taxi aviliable )

Comment: Ok I now what's your problem. Now, could you post where you get the `$date`? And what's the meaning of `$this->db->where('taxiId', $i);`? How is it possible to know the `taxi_id` from loops?

Comment: @nmfzone: 1) $date is todays Date 

2) yes,you are right  taxi_id coming from loops ( for every taxi status/ loop working according to number of taxi )

Comment: I still don't know how is it possible to know `taxi_id` from loops. What if `user_id` 2, is booking taxi with id 1, 4, 6? Since the totalTaxi for `user_id` 2 is 3.

Comment: I know the answer for your problem, but I need to clarify that. Since it's not make sense for me, it's weird.

Comment: @nmfzone: okay let me explain what i tried and why 

1)  For example, First of all i am getting User's (userId =2) total taxi (3) 
2) Now i am using loop for check ( from table "booking") whether User(3) taxiId ( 1 or 2 or 3 coming from loop) record exist or not , if exist it means taxi is right now booked and if taxiId not exist it means taxi is aviliable 

3) now i just want to show/fetch status in both conditions ,whether taxi is booked nor aviliable, thats it

Comment: You're not answering my question. What if `user_id` 2, is booking the taxi with id 1, 4, 6 (so the TotalTaxi is 3, right)? Then, the loop just check whether `taxi_id` 1, 2, 3 is booked or not, but not checking the taxi 4, 6 is booked or not.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean `aviliable`? Should it be `available`?

Comment: @nmfzone: this is not possible, becuase in "booking" table there must be taxiid value is 1 or 2 or 3,  because it will be serialnumber , 3 means 1 or 2 or 3 .......not 2 or 4 or 5, hope you understand my point

Comment: @nmfzone: for exmaple if any user from "taxiInfo" table have totaltaxi =3 then its value must be 1 or 2 or 3 in "booking" table

Comment: That's what I mean. Ok, let me try. Since I don't know why it's like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I must answer based on your information. Since I think your DB is weird (or maybe it's because my little knowledge). A lot information that's not clear, for example:

- How is it possible `TotalTaxi` 3 means it's `taxi_id` 1 or 2 or 3.
- What is `taxinumber`? There is no information about it.

```php
$userId = $_POST['userId'];
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('taxiInfo');
$this->db->where('userId', $userId);
$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    $rows = $query->row_array();
    $totaltaxi = $rows['TotalTaxi'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $taxiStatuses = [];

    for ($i=1; $i <= $totaltaxi; $i++) {
        $this->db->select('b.*');
        $this->db->from('booking b');
        $this->db->where('userId', $userId);
        $this->db->where('taxiId', $i);
        $this->db->where('serviceDate', $date);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        $taxiStatuses[] = [
            'user_id' => $userId,
            'taxi_id' => $i,
            'status' => $query->num_rows() > 0 ? 'booked' : 'available',
        ];
    }

    var_dump($taxiStatuses);die();
}
```

Comment: showing every record "booked", but actually only "1" record should showing booked

Comment: @deepikaaggarwal How is it possible? Could you show me what's your complete code right now?